# leaflet sidebar v2: adding buttons & icons

Tags: javascript, button, icons, leaflet, sidebar

I was wondering if anyone figured out a way to add more buttons onto the sidebar with custom icons. It seems like it would be very useful to have the ability to add buttons along the sidebar pane. Any help on this would be appreciated! 
Here is the link to the sidebar: https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better dig down this documentation. Here is the file where you can add more custom buttons [sidebar-v2/examples/index.html](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/blob/master/examples/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find this link (https://github.com/noerw/sidebar-v2/blob/0b4452dc689b1d093fb0b423ef1cd746da24a4aa/js/leaflet-sidebar.js) where an addPanel function is added to the original source code.